# To Tableless or not to tableless: Html expanding box with custom corners

Tags: html, css

i'm running into problems using DIV's to style a contentbox for my website. It basically looks like this:

```
          container
+--------------------------+
|+--+------------------+--+|
||c1|        r1        |c2||
|+--+------------------+--+|
||  |                  |  ||
||  |                  |  ||
||r4|     content      |r2||
||  |                  |  ||
||  |                  |  ||
|+--+------------------+--+|
||c4|        r3        |c3||
|+--+------------------+--+|
+--------------------------+
```

The width/height of r1,r2,r3 and r4 are unknown. They all have a 1px (tall or wide) gradient which repeats itself over the background.

The corners have 5x5px pngs (rounded, with transparant background).

The problem is that I do not know width or height of the content, and thus not of the r1 through r4's. There isn't really a way of saying in css:

```
r1 {width: container.width - 2x5px};
```

I know this could be done with javascript, but i want to avoid that.

**Isn't it just easier to use a table in this case? It does look like a table to me :)**

Comment: Make the gradients wider/taller than a single pixel. Some browsers have problems with this, latest I have observed is IE8...

Comment: No this is not the real issue. Please read my comment at the table-answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a table to me too. I am sure I'll be branded a heretic, but sometimes it is easier to use a table than css.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id=container>
             <table>
                <tr>
                  <td id=c1></td>
                  <td id=r1></td>
                  <td id=c2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id=r4></td>
                  <td id=content></td>
                  <td id=r2></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id=c4></td>
                  <td id=r3></td>
                  <td id=c3></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: bllllllllllllllleeeeeeeeeeeechhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Is it really easier, or is it just that you are more used to it?

Comment: Guffy, please show how this can be achieved -without- using tables..? Please keep in mind all constraints.. (unknown width/height, rounded corners with transparency)

Comment: No, tables are just bad. But it isn't very pretty in css either! I'll see if I can make something.

Comment: It takes guts to do something in a table these days. Even when it's tabular data, some body going is to complain about it. Enough!

Answer (score 1):

No, this can be achieved through standard CSS. If you don't set the width or the height, they will naturally form. The height is determined by the length of the content and the width (if not specified) will fill the width of the container it is in. If the width of the container is the whole page, then it will take up the whole page...

it seems like to achieve what you're looking for you could do something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While I don't generally condone the use of non-semantic code-bloat such as this, it will certainly get the job done. You can set the corners to be the background images of the various divs in your CSS.

Comment: What about the content in r1, r2 r3 and r4? where does that go?

Comment: there is no content in there... those are design elements, or so i thought. if he needs content in there, then he has some design issues, i believe....

Comment: Byron is right, there needs to be a background image spanning the entire width or height of a row (r1 through r4)... And those cannot go under/over either of the corners, because those have transparent roundings...

Answer (score 1):

My quickly made css solution:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>CSS borders</title>
<style>


* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#container
{
    width:20%;
}

#head
{
    background-image:url(images/rounded_01.png);
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:14px;
    width:14px;
    width:100%;
}

#head-mid
{
    background-image:url(images/rounded_02.png);
    height:14px;
    margin-left:14px;
    margin-right:14px;
}

#head-right
{
    background-image:url(images/rounded_03.png);
    background-position:right top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:14px;
    width:100%;
}

#content
{
    background-image:url(images/contentleft.png);
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    height:14px;
    width:14px;
    width:100%;
}

#content-mid
{
    background-image:url(images/content.png);
    height:14px;
    margin-left:14px;
    margin-right:14px;
}

#content-right
{
    background-image:url(images/contentright.png);
    background-position:right top;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    width:100%;
}

#bottom
{
    background-image:url(images/rounded_07.png);
    background-position:left top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:14px;
    width:14px;
    width:100%;
}

#bottom-mid
{
    background-image:url(images/rounded_08.png);
    height:14px;
    margin-left:14px;
    margin-right:14px;
}

#bottom-right
{
    background-image:url(images/rounded_09.png);
    background-position:right top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:14px;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="head">
                <div id="head-right">
                    <div id="head-mid">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
                <div id="content-right">
                    <div id="content-mid">
                    <p>content here... will auto expand and resize</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
                <div id="bottom-right">
                    <div id="bottom-mid">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All files (images and psd): http://www.mediafire.com/file/zmemlw0tyyv/css.rar

Comment: The css can be optimized, I just made it this way for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

r4 fixed(5px), content liquid, r2 fixed(fixed)

See if this tool can help.

http://www.pagecolumn.com/liquidfixed/3_col_fix-liquid-fix.htm